# How to find the count of objects in an array which is a value for a key in all mongodb documents in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the collection.

```
{{
 "id" : "123",
 "likes" : [ {
       "member" : "3041" 
      },
      {
       "member" : "3141" 
     }]
},
{
 "id" : "124",
 "likes" : [ {
       "member" : "3241" 
      },
      {
       "member" : "3241" 
      },
      {
       "member" : "3341" 
     }]
}}
```

How to retrieve the count of number of objects of likes key for each document?

In this format:

```
[{
   "id" : "123",
   "likesCount" : 2
},
{
   "id" : "124",
   "likesCount" : 3
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      id: 1,
      likesCount: {
        $size: "$likes"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You are using an aggregation and in the $project part of it use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to get the length of the array.

You can see it working [**here**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0WWvfixfwzk)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to map the collection to transform the objects within it into the shape you want.

In this case we get the object and extract the id and instead of all the likes we just get the length of them.

```
let newCollection = collection.map(obj => ({
  id: obj.id,
  likesCount: obj.likes.length
}));
```

Comment: A description on the answer would be more helpful